# How can I buy songs I like from Pandora and listen to them on Google Play?

Tags: music, pandora, google-play

All the music I've bought is on Google Play. Over on Pandora, I've given "thumbs up" to a lot of tracks.  I'd like to buy the Pandora tracks and listen to them in Google Play.  But Pandora only seems to offer the ability to buy music from iTunes or Amazon MP3.

[image: buy music from iTunes or Amazon MP3]

I don't want to search for the track names on Google Play, since there may be 20 mixes of the same song, and I want the specific mix I thumbed up. **Is there a way to buy these great tracks from Pandora and listen to them on Google Play?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot manually locate the song on Google Play, you can download the song from iTunes or Amazon after you've purchased the song and then use the Google Play service to listen to them. Google actually is running a promo on this right now.

https://play.google.com/intl/en-US_us/about/music/unlock/

The site says, to use iTunes on Google Play do the following:

> Google Play helps you bring your iTunes library to your Android
>   devices. You can upload up to 50,000 of your songs from your computer
>   to Google Play for free. Once you’ve uploaded your music, it's
>   instantly available on the web and your Android phone or tablet. No
>   wires, downloading or syncing.
>
> 1. Sign up for your Google Play music library To get started, sign up for Google Play and download Music Manager, a simple desktop
>      application that lets you upload your collection from your iTunes
>      music library or any music folder on your computer to the cloud.
> 2. Sign in to Music Manager, choose where you keep your music and it starts uploading automatically. And when you add new music to your
>      computer, Music Manager can automatically add it to your library too.
>      You can upload 50,000 of your songs for free. Music Manager even adds
>      your iTunes playlists and ratings so you can start listening to your
>      favorites right away.
> 3. Now that you've set up your Google Play music library, you can access it on your Android phone or tablet and the web. Sign in and all
>      your music is just there, like magic. And when you upgrade to the
>      latest Android device, your music comes along too. You'll never be
>      without your favorite artists again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless pandora add a Google play link, no you can't do this in the way you want